# Magento 2 custom module not loading and it throws error

Tags: magento2, module, custom

I am using windows 7.

> app\etc\config.php

```
<?php
return array (
  'modules' => 
  array (
    'Test_Module1' => 1,
  ),
);
?>
```

When I add My `Test_Module1` in `app\etc\config.php` admin all pages(catalog,sales) throws error and and `127.0.0.1/magento20/module1/index/index` url throws errors
Error is:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:56:"Setup version for module 'Test_Module1' is not specified";i:1;s:2248:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\framework\Module\DbVersionInfo.php(56): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('Test_Module1', false)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\framework\Module\DbVersionInfo.php(79): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('Test_Module1')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(55): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCookieVali...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie.php(78): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 [internal function]: Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento20\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:128:"/magento20/admin/admin/system_config/edit/section/advanced/key/501ed24319079b7b02cc894a5cb412b17b878bd2df98afefe85a9539080cb8c9/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/magento20/index.php";}
```

and If I remove My module from `app\etc\config.php` admin works fine but `127.0.0.1/magento20/module1/index/index` does not work

> magento20/app/code/composer.json

```
{
"name": "test/module1",
"description": "test module1 for Magento 2",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0"
},
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
        "test\\module1\\": ""
    }
}
}
```

> magento20/app/code/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Module1',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

> magento20/app/code/Test/Module1/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Test_Module1" schema_version="1.0.0" setup_version="1.0.0"/> 
</config>
```

> magento20/app/code/Test/Module1/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="module1" frontName="module1">
            <module name="Test_Module1" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> magento20/app/code/Test/Module1/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php 
namespace Test\Module1\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        die('hi');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `composer.json` & `registration.php` need to be in `app/code/Test/Module1`. The attribute `schema_version` is not valid (in stable M2 version). Did you clean cache? Did you run `setup:upgrade` command line?

Comment: @test, is it working?

Comment: Check setup_module table if there is an entry of your module then delete it and run setup upgrade command again.

Answer (score 0):

move your `registration.php` and `composer.json` files to your **Test/Module1** root folder

and

change your `module.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Test_Module1" schema_version="1.0.0" setup_version="1.0.0"/> 
</config>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Module1" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Still not working please help me,I tried many tutorials but failed,I tried your code but still not work

Comment: I also clear cache

Comment: @test, which version you are using?

Comment: I downloaded yesterday from magento website Magento-CE-2.0.0-2015-11-17-05-47-46

Answer (score 0):

Add **registration.php** at location (magento20/app/code/Test/Module1/registration.php)

**Code :**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Module1',
    __DIR__
);
```

Open Command line in folder root of magento and run commands `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

[image: magento setup upgrade]

[More details](http://www.venustheme.com/how-to-create-magento-2-module/)

Comment: Still not working please help me,I tried many tutorials but failed,

Comment: I also clear cache

Comment: Open Command line in folder root of magento and run commands
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I tried php bin/magento setup:upgrade command.After apply this command  automatically removed 'Test_Module1'=>1  from app\etc\config.php.

Comment: after upgrade command ,My Test_Module1 does not display means that my Test_module1 not loaded

Comment: Pls follow this link : http://www.venustheme.com/how-to-create-magento-2-module/

Comment: recently I followed this venustheme.com url and my magento20 ,right click on composer.json and click composer install option and run a php bin/magento setup:upgrade      code all module upgrade  but my module not upgrade.

Comment: First I am uninstalling my magento 2 instance and will reinstall magento 2 then will create custom module following by you mentioned url(venustheme url.....)

Comment: Yes after your follow this url

Comment: Thanks bro for reference link.Now works perfect.thanks again

Comment: Please check your module version in database then install new version again